# how to write a regex for a given string -Regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not so good at framing regex and I need help on this one:

I want to do some regex on my string:

```
str= '(OS:"Windows" OR OS:"VMware") AND tags.tag.name:"test" and not asset:(name: "somename" or name="somename3" or name="somename4")';
```

we can ignore the key name and values here and focus on the format.

with regex, I want the str to be replaced and new string to look like:

```
newStr= '(OS:"Windows" OR OS:"VMware") AND tags.tag:(name:"test") and not sev.name: "somename"'
```

so basically replace this part `tags.tag.name:"test"` with `tags.tag:(name:"test")` with regex.

I tried this:

```
test = str.replace(/tags\.tag\.(([^<>=]+?\(.+?\))|.+?){1}($|(\s+?(and|or)\s+?))/ig, function(a, b, match2, match3, op) {
                    return String.format('{0}:({1}){2}', insert, b, op ? op:'');
                });//here insert= '"tags.tag"'
```

but the o/p gives me:

```
"(OS:"Windows" OR OS:"VMware") AND tags.tag:(name:"test" AND not asset:(name: "somename" or name="somename3" or name="somename4"))"
```

which frames wrong query for me.

HOw to achieve

```
newStr= '(OS:"Windows" OR OS:"VMware") AND tags.tag:(name:"test") and not sev.name: "somename"'
```

instead of

```
"(OS:"Windows" OR OS:"VMware") AND tags.tag:(name:"test" AND not asset:(name: "somename" or name="somename3" or name="somename4"))"
```

with the above regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work: `(?<=tags\.tag)\.(\w+):"(\w+)"`

Replace that pattern with `:($1:"$2")`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HoW62p/2)

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that ```name``` is subject to change, the string could have: ```tags.tag.id:"1"``` as well, only ```tags.tag``` is constant, thnks

Comment: should be fixed now